# screen recorder tools - open source/integrated with test management

Tags: testing, screenshot, microsoft-test-manager

I have a two-part question:

1) what are available for open source 'screen recorder' tools?  Here is what I got so far, but I have not evaluated them yet as I'm trying to collect the list first:

http://camstudio.org/

http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/

http://shutter-project.org/

http://getgreenshot.org/

http://autoscreen.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/capturedit/

2) Is there any test management/manual test software that currently uses screen recorders with manual testing to record what the tester does during each test case (instead of requiring them to manually print-screen one step at a time).

Intent is to find a better way to, screen-by-screen, see what gets entered on the 'screens' throughout the test case cycle to help with problem identification if a problem occurs.  'Screens' could be identified as either web-based (traditional or ajax) or thick-client (java, .net, whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recordmydesktop and gtk-recordmydesktop. It simple, lightweight and will give u a nice video screencast. Just install and press the stop or play button from your panel, videos will be saved in *.ogv formats.

`$ sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop gtk-recordmydesktop`